# How to schedule an autosys job to run every min?

Tags: autosys

How can I set a job in autosys which will run every?

Please help me how I can specify then start time parameter. I am new to this JIL script.

Also where can I get the complete details about scheduling a job using JIL script?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [start_mins](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/workload-automation-ae-and-workload-control-center/11-3-6-SP8/reference/ae-job-information-language/jil-job-definitions/start-mins-attribute-define-the-minutes-to-run-a-job.html) attribute